# Change date format for an index in python from yyyy-dd-mm to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, jupyter-notebook, datetime-format

I have a dataframe with dates in the index and another column with values for those dates.

My index is currently in datetime type and reads `YYYY-dd-mm`, I would like it to read as `YYYY-mm-dd`

After having searched for an answer, it will get changed to a str and I will have to change it back. Trouble is, I have not seen anyone do this for when the column is an index.

i.e. I have tried `df["Date"].dt.strftime('%Y%m%d')` but this does not work as "Date" is not a column rather it is an index

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a format yyyy-dd-mm means that the data type is string; you can parse [to datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and [set index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html#pandas.DataFrame.set_index) like

```
import pandas as pd
# dummy example
df = pd.DataFrame({'v': [1,2]}, index=['2020-13-02', '2020-14-02'])

df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%d-%m'))

# now you have:
# df
#             v
# 2020-02-13  1
# 2020-02-14  2
```

note that this will give you a [datetime index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html). if you want string, use

```
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%Y-%d-%m').strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```